# Deprecate spring-security-oauth as a client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I want to move from spring-security-oauth to spring-security now, but I cannot find any way of doing so.
I searched a lot and all I could find are examples about providing an OAuth Endpoint.

My current OAuth2RestTemplate is a bit complicated, as the oauth server is not using the standard way for identification, inspired by the post [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/311#issuecomment-364149437).

This is my OAuth2RestTemplate:

```
fun createOAuthRestTemplate(resourceDetails: OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails): OAuth2RestTemplate {

    val clientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider = ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider()
    clientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.setAuthenticationHandler(<myClientAuthenticationHandler extends ClientAuthenticationHandler>))
    clientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.setRequestFactory(requestFactory)

    val oauthTemplate = OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails)
    oauthTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(clientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider)
    return oauthTemplate
  }
```

The [spring migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide) unfortunately didn't help me much as it just mentions the RestTemplate, but doesn't go into detail.

```
[...] 
A Simplified RestTemplate and WebClient
Spring Security OAuth extends RestTemplate, introducing OAuth2RestTemplate. 
This class needs to be instantiated and exposed as a @Bean.

Spring Security chooses to favor composition and instead exposes an 
OAuth2AuthorizedClientService, which is useful for creating RestTemplate interceptors 
[...]
```

My question is now:
How do I get the same functionality in a rest template using spring-security?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*OAuth 2.0 with Spring Security 5 and RestTemplate*

Spring Security 5.2 does not have direct support for `RestTemplate`, it has beans that simplify the work, though. The recommendation is to [use `WebClient`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/webclient/src/main/java/example/WebClientConfiguration.java), if you can, instead of `RestTemplate`.

However, if you need to use `RestTemplate`, then you first want to create an `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager`:

```
@Bean
OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizeClientManager(
    ClientRegistrationRepository clients,
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {

    DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager manager =
        new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clients, authorizedClients);

    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build();
    manager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
    return manager;
}
```

This manager bean is where you make decisions on the kinds of grant types that you want your interceptor to negotiate for you. It is similar to the `ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider` in your post.

Second, you'll want to create a `RestTemplate` interceptor. It will ask the manager to get it a token and then add that token to the `Authorization` header:

```
@Component
public class OAuth2AuthorizedClientInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager manager;

    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientInterceptor(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(
        HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) 
        throws IOException {

        Authentication principal = // ...

        OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest
             .withClientRegistrationId("foo-client")
             .principal(principal)
             .build();
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = 
            this.manager.authorize(authorizedRequest);

        HttpHeaders headers = httpRequest.getHeaders();
        headers.setBearerAuth(authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getValue());

        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

In Spring Security 5, each client is represented by a registration id. The registration id is what goes in place of `foo-client`.

The `principal` will depend a bit on your situation, but it is typically sufficient to use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`. If there is no user in context, you might consider `AnonymousAuthenticationToken`, e.g.

```
Authentication principal = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken
    ("key", "anonymous", AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"));
```

Finally, you can add your interceptor to your `RestTemplate`:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate rest(OAuth2AuthorizedClientInterceptor interceptor) {
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    rest.getInterceptors().add(interceptor);
    return rest;
}
```

*JWT Client Authentication*

As for the post you referred to, it is doing a JWT for client authentication. For this support, you'll want to look at configuring a `DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient`. This would be part of the manager that you built in the first step:

```
@Bean
OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizeClientManager(
    ClientRegistrationRepository clients,
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {

    DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager manager =
        new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clients, authorizedClients);

    DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient tokenClient =
            new DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
    tokenClient.setRequestEntityConverter(fooConverter);

    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials(cc -> cc
                        .accessTokenResponseClient(tokenClient))
                .build();
    manager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
    return manager;
}
```

`fooConverter` is any converter that you specify for creating the appropriate `RequestEntity` instance. Something like:

```
// ...
tokenClient.setRequestEntityConverter(grantRequest -> {
    ClientRegistration client = grantRequest.getClientRegistration();
    // ... formulate JWT
    // ... create `RequestEntity`, including `Authorization` header
    // that includes JWT as the bearer token
});
```

This setter, `setRequestEntityConverter` is the functional equivalent of `ClientAuthenticationHandler` in the legacy project.

Comment: thanks, I will have a look at the Webclient, but otherwise look at your example for the RestTemplate :)

Comment: where can I add the code described in [this post](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/311#issuecomment-364149437)?
All I am trying to do is basically that hack. I understand enough now to see, that it doesn't matter if I use RestTemplate or WebClient for this, but I need to understand at what point I can hook up my AuthenticationHandler into the new authorization mechanism. Do you have an idea how I can do that? @jzheaux

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @RuthiRuth, I've added a new section that talks about the functional equivalent for ClientAuthenticationHandler.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @jzheaux. I had to make some adaptions in order to get to where I am with your example, but I am stuck now. I have the problem, that when I use your interceptor, at the point `OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("foo-client").build();` I get the error "principal cannot be null". Where ever I look in the web, I find a controller which also gets the Authentication object, but where can I get that in an interceptor? Also tried webclient but not familiar enough to adapt and it just says 401 there :( Any ideas?

Comment: The adaption I had to make was in the manager. I cannot reach the 'accessTokenResponseClient' so had to use
`.clientCredentials { configurer -> configurer.accessTokenResponseClient(tokenClient) }`(kotlin) Maybe you could edit your answer - or I can edit that at the end with your permission, so I can accept your answer as a working example for others? :)

Comment: did you also have a look at the comment before? Still not sure which Authentication object I need to use, this way it does not work. I added a `AuthenticationLessAuthentication`, but it feels kind of hacky ;) so is there a propert way to get an Authentication object?

Comment: `OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.principal` is required since an `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` is always associated with a `Principal`. In most cases, the `OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.principal` should be the same as `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` that was used to save the  `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` via `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService.saveAuthorizedClient`.

Comment: whoops, @RuthiRuth, sorry I missed your comment. I've added some detail there.

Comment: thank you so much for your help jzheaux. It works - now with the editing the example is completely functional as well. Many many thanks for your help :)

Comment: my pleasure, @RuthiRuth!

Comment: note @jzheaux I believe there is a typo, the class DefaultClientCredentialsAccessTokenResponseClient does not exist. I think you mean DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient (no "Access") which you had mentioned prior to the code sample. Thanks!!